# Update Data Connection to latest DB version on Visual Studio 17

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I'm currently using Visual Studio to develop an ASP.NET/C# web application that relies on a SQL Server database for the data behind. From the moment I originally created the Data Connection through VS, I've gone back and changed certain things in the DB (certain column types, added test rows, etc) through SQL Server Management Studio. However, none of these changes are reflected in the VS application, which is a pain because I am constantly getting errors because of the mismatch. For example, I tried to insert a string into a column that was originally an int and I get an error when trying to process the query through my code behind, even though the actual DB lets me run the query just fine through SQL Server Manager.

This mismatch is so bad that if I run the same query (**SELECT * FROM Project**) on both SQL Server Manager and Visual Studio I get completely different results: [SQL Server Management Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CNJkN.png) vs [Visual Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2LYeQ.png)

I've tried refreshing my connection on Server Explorer to no end and even created a new connection string on Web.config to see if this would somehow fix it, but nothing seems to work. I found an article that explains that VS creates a local version of the DB during the build, but it seems like the solution it provides only works for non-ASP.NET projects because I don't have a bin/Debug DB.

Any suggestions to get Visual Studio to reflect the latest version of my schema/data? Thank you!

Comment: The article I found is: https://visualstudiomagazine.com/blogs/tool-tracker/2012/05/dealing-with-local-databases-or-why-your-updates-dont-stick.aspx

Comment: Just double check your connection strings to make sure everything points at the same database.

Comment: Yup, same database server and information. I've used Object Explorer and while there's other databases on the server, the Initial Catalog is pointing to the correct db too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your example files, you are working on two different databases.

Execute the following command in SQL Server Management Studio and in Visual Studio.  You will likely see that the filenames listed are different.

```
exec sp_helpfile
```

If so, then you are not connecting to the same server/database in both environments.  You can click on the database in Visual Studio to see the "Connection string" in the Properties window.  Check it against your web.config connection string.

Comment: Not entirely sure if this fixed it since I didn't actually change my code, but I ran the command and the DB connection got refreshed and now both databases are in sync! Thanks a ton

Comment: It sounds like your VS connection was refreshed and is now using the same parameters as SSMS.  That command above will not change anything but should help with troubleshooting if you have problems in the future.